# How to create bindable commands in Custom control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Assuming a code like below,

```
public class SomeViewModel{
      ICommand ReloadCommand{get...}
      ICommand SaveCommand{get..}
}

//SomeView.xaml
<SomeCustomControl Reload="ReloadCommand" Save="SaveCommand" /> //NOT SURE HOW??

//SomeCustomContro.xaml
<SomeCustomControl x:Name="someCustomControl">
<Button Command={Binding ElementName=someCustomControl, Path=Reload />
<Button Command={Binding ElementName=someCustomControl, Path=Save />
</SomeCustomControl>

//SomeCustomControl.xaml.cs
.....  //NOT SURE HOW TO ALLOW BINDING TO A ICOMMAND ??
```

In my SomeCustomControl, I need to support "binding of ICommand in xaml".
I understand DependencyProperties could be bind like this, but in this case I need to bind ICommand.

**EDIT**
I can use the `DataContext` `SomeView` in `SomeCustomControl`. There is more logic and separation between the two which I can not dissolve. I 'must' maintain a reference of Reload/Save `ICommands` somewhere in my `SomeCustomControl`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Let me get you straight, you want to bind to the `Reload` and `Save` right?

So that needs creating, declaring and defining two dependency properties `ReloadCommandProperty` and `SaveCommandProperty` of type `ICommand` for `SomeCustomControl`.

So assuming that `SomeCustomControl` derives from `Control` ...

```
public class SomeCustomControl : Control
{
    public static DependencyProperty ReloadCommandProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ReloadCommand",
            typeof (ICommand),
            typeof (SomeCustomControl));

    public static DependencyProperty SaveCommandProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SaveCommand",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(SomeCustomControl));

    public ICommand ReloadCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)GetValue(ReloadCommandProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(ReloadCommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)GetValue(SaveCommandProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(SaveCommandProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

After this proper binding to `RelodCommand` and `SaveCommand` properties will start working...

```
     <SomeCustomControl RelodCommand="{Binding ViewModelReloadCommand}"
                        SaveCommand="{Binding ViewModelSaveCommand}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a property that will return your command and bind this property wherever needed.

```
private ICommand _reloadCommand;
public ICommand ReloadCommand
{
  get 
  { 
    if(_reloadCommand == null) _reloadCommand = CreateReloadCommand();
    return _reloadCommand;
  }
}
```

Change the binding in your code to

```
<Button Command={Binding ReloadCommand}" />
```

And bind the custom control DataContext to the view model that contains the commands.

Comment: Do you mean I can directly bind a ICommand instance to a property in a control?? Also, what is "CreateReloadCommand" for? This command instance will be created in ViewModel, and SomeCustomControl just needs to store that instance reference (using xaml binding).

Comment: You can bind value of ICommand type to whatever you want, the most meaningful dependency property for binding is `ButtonBase.CommandProperty`. `CreateReloadCommand` is a method creating your command - I did not wanted to write the command creation and initialization code. When I was typing my answer, you have methods for commands in your code (you've changed them later).