# WPF - How to draw lines between custom controls programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2017

so I'm trying to make a program that allows users to design simple programs using modules with different functions in WPF.

I've created custom controls for my modules that look like this:

```
    <Border Height="75" Width="150" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
    <Grid Background="Gray" Height="75" Width ="150">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Double" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="Aquamarine"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Name="IncomingConnection" Height="15" Width="15" Background="Black" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

            <Button Name="OutgoingConnection" Grid.Column="2" Height="15" Width="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Black" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <Button Name="OutgoingData" Grid.Column="2" Height="15" Width="15" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Aquamarine" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Anyways, I want to be able to click on one of these buttons (incomingConnection or outgoingConnection), and have a line connect the two buttons.

Other information: The custom controls are all being placed inside thumbs so they can be dragged around. Everything is on a canvas. I don't want to create a line between the controls, but instead between the buttons on the controls.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: What did you try yourself? Did you implement some [commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660547/how-to-create-bindable-commands-in-custom-control)?

Comment: Mostly just research, everything I've found that might work seems to be exclusive to the control as a whole, and not for that specific button. I Tried getting the point of the button when it was pressed but that didn't work once the control was dragged elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a class for the lines that contains the x and y coordinates for both endpoints. I would put an instance for each line in to a list on the view model.  Then use an `ItemsControl` bound to that property with a `Canvas` as the template.  You can then use a WPF `Line` control as the `ItemTemplate` for the `ItemsControl`.  You can bind the `Line` control's `X1`, `Y1`, `X2`, and `Y2` to the endpoint properties of the line class that was created at the beginning.

With that setup, all you have to do is add instances of your line class to the list and they will automatically show up on the `Canvas`.